# How do I connect to a cluster with remote-ssh on vscode?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, ssh, cluster-computing, openssh

I am trying to connect to a ovh cluster using the ssh connection. I can connect but when im connected, the server crash immediatly with this log errors :

```
[13:00:38.785] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[13:00:38.788] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:640937)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:638303)
    at e (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:698535)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:720404
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:724063)
    at async /Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:695240
    at async C (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:693291)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:694780)
    at async I (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:717627)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:721434)
    at async /Users/kopp/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.106.5/out/extension.js:2:905238
[13:00:38.791] ------
```

The weird thing is that I have acces to another cluster since 6 months on the same device (vs code) with no problem).

Thanks for your help

I tried to connect a ovh cluster and it failed
I tried to install a public/private key but does not work.